# Incorrect proportions on imagemagick paste image

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I'm having proportion issue.

Here, you can see the code outputs correctly, having the circle on top left and the text aligned.

http://ec2-3-14-255-196.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/genphoto/example1.png

Here, you can see the same result for a much larger image which still upholds the circle and text but the pasted image outout
shows much smaller.

http://ec2-3-14-255-196.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/genphoto/example2.png

Heres my code:

```
<?php
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

// create imagine interface
$imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
$image = $imagine->open("new.png");

// paste and resize circle
$image2 = $imagine->open("circle.png");
$image2->resize(new \Imagine\Image\Box(250,250));
$image->paste($image2,new \Imagine\Image\Point(0,0));

//  add text
$Palette = new \Imagine\Image\Palette\RGB();
$TextColor = $Palette->color('#000', 100);
$TextFont= new \Imagine\Gd\Font("./thorne_shaded.ttf",13,$TextColor);
$TextBox = $TextFont->box( "test texte" );
$TextCenterPosition = new \Imagine\Image\Point\Center( $TextBox );
$CenteredTextPosition = new \Imagine\Image\Point(35,100);
$image->draw()->text("test text",$TextFont,$CenteredTextPosition);

// save image
$image->save("example2.png");
```

How can i make it so i can pass any image into the code and the results will be equal (looks like example 1) Im sure its a mathematical approach but i cant figure out the algorithm (maybe an aspect ratio?)

Comment: You need to scale your point size of the text and circle according to the size of the image, not just use the same fixed sizes. Find a size that works for some (reference) image. Get the image size, then scale the reference point size and the reference circle dimensions by the ratio of the big image to the reference image.

Comment: Easy enough thanks